# angular app not loading the page into view and restarting itself

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I am trying to build an angular app that searches a Github user based on their username and displays the list of their repos.
Next when the user clicks on any repo name it should display the list of open issues and contributors.
here's the plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/6ZzIkB7W1HgxQtuQjo5k?p=preview

> please visit the plunk and make a test run on the app, i'm not able to explain my issue properly

my repocontroller js.

```
(function(){

var app = angular.module('plunker');
app.controller('RepoCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, $http, $log){
    var username = $routeParams.username;
    var reponame = $routeParams.reponame;



    var onSuccess = function(response){
      $scope.repo = response.data;
      $http.get($scope.repo.contributors_url)
      .then(onCollab , onError);
    };

    var onCollab = function(response){
        $scope.contributors = response.data;
    };

    var onError = function(reason){
    $scope.error = "Data Load Error";
    };

    //GET https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/contributors
    $http.get('https://api.github.com/repos/' + 'username/' + 'reponame')
    .then(onSuccess, onError);
});

}());
```

I'm encountering a trouble in the last stage i.e when the user clicks on any repo name instead of loading repo.html page , the application reloads the main page again.
 Can you help me out please ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your site's default url is like `http://localhost/#!/main`
You have to chenge your links with #!/ like in user.html

```
<a href="#!/repo/{{user.login}}/{{repo.name}}">{{repo.name}}</a>
```

and in repo.html

```
<a href="#!/main">Back To Main</a>
<a href="#!/user/{{repo.owner.login}}">Back To {{repo.owner.login}}</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `#` from anchor link which is in `ng-repeat="repo in repos | orderBy:repoSort"` show below code for more info

```
<div>
  <h2>{{error}}</h2>
  <h1>{{user.name}}</h1>
  <a href="{{user.blog}}" target=_blank>{{user.blog}}</a>
  <h1>{{user.email}}</h1>
  <h1>{{user.location}}</h1>
  <img ng-src="{{user.avatar_url}}" title={{user.name}} width="250px" id="userDetails"> OrderBy:
  <select ng-model="repoSort">
    <option value="-stargazers_count">Stars</option>
    <option value="name">Name (A-Z)</option>
    <option value="-name">Name (Z-A)</option>
  </select>

</div>



<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Stars</th>
      <th>Language</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="repo in repos | orderBy:repoSort">
      <td>
        <a href="/repo/{{user.login}}/{{repo.name}}">{{repo.name}}</a>
      </td>
      <td>{{repo.stargazers_count | number}}</td>
      <td>{{repo.language}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<a href='#/main'>Back To Main</a>
```